# nginx single location to multiple upstreams

Tags: nginx, location

I need to proxy single location to two upstreams. There are two upstreams defined:

```
upstream django {
   server unix:///home/copilot/django.sock;
}
upstream trip_storage {
   server 127.0.0.1:10500;
}
```

Usually everything was proxied to Django via this location:

```
location / {
   uwsgi_pass         django;

   uwsgi_param   Host                 $host;
   uwsgi_param   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
   uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-Proto    $http_x_forwarded_proto;

   include uwsgi_params;
}
```

Now I have to proxy requests coming to /api/trip to new backend called trip_storage but for testing and comparison it should also be routed to legacy backend in Django. I have tried to do it by creating two new locations:

```
location /api/trip/ {
   uwsgi_pass         triglavtest_copilot;

   uwsgi_param   Host                 $host;
   uwsgi_param   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
   uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-Proto    $http_x_forwarded_proto;

   include uwsgi_params;
   # Send to trip storage
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://trip_storage/api/trip_storage/smartphone/;
}
```

But this configuration does not work, instead it is proxied only to defined proxy_pass, ignoring uwsgi_pass. Is there some other way to proxy single location to multiple upstreams?